# Is it possible to fetch API without useEffect in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello i'm newbie here...
I found my friend's code when he using `useState` instead of using `useEffect` to fetch the API.
I tried it and it worked, the code didn't cause an error and infinite loops.

here is for the code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { IN_THEATER, POSTER } from "../../../constant/movies";
import { GlobalGet } from "../../../utilities/fetch";

const Service = () => {
  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState({ data: null, poster: null });

  const fetchMovieData = async () => {
    try {
      let movieRes = await GlobalGet({ url: `${IN_THEATER}` });
      return movieRes;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const fetchPoster = async () => {
    try {
      let posterRes = await GlobalGet({ url: `${POSTER}` });
      return posterRes;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setMovieData({
      data: await fetchMovieData(),
      poster: await fetchPoster(),
    });
  };

  useState(() => { //<=here it is
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return {
    movieData,
  };
};

export default Service;
```

And my question is, why it could be happen ? why using `useState` there doesn't cause an infinite loops ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `useState()` function can accept an *initializer* function as its first argument:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(initializerFunction)
```

When a function is passed to `useState()`, that function is only called once before the component initially mounts. In your case below, the initializer function is an anonymous arrow function:

```js
useState(() => { // <-- Initializer function invoked once
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Here, the initializer function is `() => { fetchData(); }`, which is invoked once before the initial mount, so the `fetchData()` method is only called once. The array that is passed as the second argument `[]` is useless and doesn't do anything in this case as it's ignored by `useState()`. The above useState would behave the same if you did `useState(fetchData);`. Because `fetchData()` is only called once on the initial mount, any state updates of your component don't cause the `fetchData()` function to execute again as it's within the initializer function.

With that said, `useState()` shouldn't be used for fetching data on mount of your component, that's what [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) should be used for instead.

Comment: Just addition: react also asks you to have the initializer function pure (though bit strange since it should be called once): https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#my-initializer-or-updater-function-runs-twice.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Thanks for the addition :) Yeah, it's interesting that it should be pure. I guess that while it's only called once per component, it could be executed multiple times if there are multiple instances of the component, so you'd want the initial state to be the same for each of the component instances if they're each called in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Generally it's possible to fetch data from outside of the useEffect hook.

Somewhere in the body of your component...

```
const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(false)

const someFetchFunc = asyunc (url) => {

setFetchedData(!fetchedData)

const res = await fetch(url)
const data = await res.json()
setMovieData(data)

}

!fetchedData && someFetchFunc()
```

But this is an antipattern. In this case developer lacks a whole toolset of dealing with possible issues. What if fetching fails?

So, it's generally a good idea to handle all the side effects like fetching in a place that was intended for that. It's useEffect hook)